# Migrating a raid array into a new case on the same hardware

Tags: raid, hardware

I'm transferring my current server's guts into a new, rack mounted, case.
Not changing any of the hardware - just taking it out of its current tower, and dumping it in the new box.

System specs (sorry I skipped these originally):
- Hardware RAID - not sure the exact controller spec. it's the on-board controller on a BIOSTAR TA790GXE motherboard.
- OS - Small Business Server 2008
- Drives - 2x Hitachi 2tb in Raid 1

It's a straight transfer of all the same hardware into a new case. My only real concern is:
Can I break the raid array if I swap drive order when I plug it all back in?

Are there any special considerations to ensure my Raid 1 array survives the trip in tact?
Do I need to ensure the same drives end up in the same SATA ports?
They'll end up taking the same ports between then, but the order may switch - could that cause problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to say with any certainty as you don't provide any details whatsoever. That said if the machine has the same motherboard, disk controller (in the same slot) and disks (again in the same cabling configuration) you *should* be just fine.

Comment: What that nice Mr. Chopper said.  Is it software RAID, hardware RAID?  OS if the former?  RAID controller if the latter?

Comment: Sorry for the overall lack of detail in my question. I'll be more clear, and do more research in the future. Lesson learned :)